# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder_765:0', which has shape '(1,)'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a trained an InceptionV3 from scratch on a custom dataset containing 100 classes. Initialized the CNN model on Keras. I am now trying to generate adversarial examples for this model of mine using Foolbox, however I am getting the above error. Where am I going wrong? The library(Foolbox) seems to be working fine for others and my model gets past the image classification process correctly without any error but the wrapper model generates it.

```python
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
import foolbox
from foolbox.models import KerasModel
from foolbox.attacks import LBFGSAttack
from foolbox.criteria import TargetClass
import numpy as np
import foolbox
keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)

model=load_model('standard_inceptionV3.h5')
fmodel = foolbox.models.KerasModel(model, bounds=(0, 255))

from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('/home/shikhar/Downloads/suit.jpeg')
img = img.resize((224,224))
img = np.asarray(img)
img = img[:, :, :3]

lab=model.predict(np.expand_dims(img, axis=0))
label=np.argmax(lab,axis=1)

from foolbox.criteria import Misclassification, TargetClass
attack = foolbox.attacks.FGSM(model=fmodel)
adversarial = attack(img, label,unpack=False)
```

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem

Comment: Which line produces the error ? Also can we see your original keras model ?

Comment: It's the standard InceptionV3 from Keras, randomly initialized and trained on my 100 class dataset. The error is generated after I run the last line (attack).